# How to enable file auditing for exchange server V15 folder

Tags: security, exchange, windows-server-2016, user-permissions, audit

So I want to enable auditing on this specific folder V15 located under program files>Microsoft>Exchange server

But on the auditing tab I get a Message "you must be an administrator or have been given the appropriate privileges to view the auditing properties of this object"

When I click "Continue", the "Auditing" tab disappears.
I have already enabled in group policy

How do I get the option to add and not get this message or is there any other way ??

Comment: The message is quite clear: you should have the right to view the auditing properties of this folder. It looks like you didn't.

Comment: @LeRouteur I am logged in using the administrator account ! ? and even my user account has full permissions but that also didn't work ?

Comment: Which one? The local one or the one from the domain?

Comment: @LeRouteur I am connecting using RDP...if thats what u r asking ?

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted to know: have you an Active Directory domain? If so, are you using the administrator account from this domain or the one of the local machine?

Comment: ok...from the domain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113746/discussion-between-lerouteur-and-david-kent).

Comment: Have you tried to modify the UAC for your current account? Try to reduce it and see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify the UAC for your current account? Try to reduce it and see if there is any difference.[image]

Comment: Its already at "Never notify" :/

Comment: Do you encounter the same issue if you enable **Auditing** for other folders with the current account?

Comment: yes same issue..

Comment: on my local pc I can do it...But on the server the auditing tab just vanishes as soon as I click on Continue

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Is your account a member of the **Enterprise Admin/Domain Admin** group? Is your computer a member of the **Exchange Trusted Subsystem** group?